# What does the following code analysis mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-analysis

I have an object instantiated like the following in only one place in my code(AggregateFunctions).

```
    private String selectColumns() {
        String query = "SELECT ";

        if (this.distinctResults) {
            query = query + "DISTINCT ";
        }

        SelectColumn selectColumn = new SelectColumn(this);

        if (!this.applyAggregation) {
            for (Object object : this.columns) {
                query = selectColumn.selectColumn(query, object);
            }
        } else {
            AggregateFunctions aggregateFunctions = new AggregateFunctions(this);
            query = query + aggregateFunctions.select();
        }
        //Remove extra ', '
        query = query.substring(0, query.length() - 2) + " FROM ";
        return query;
    }
```

**The constructors:**

```
    public AggregateFunctions(@NotNull SqlQueryGenerator sqlQueryGenerator) {
        this.spaceEncloser = sqlQueryGenerator.getSpaceEncloser();
        this.selectColumn = new SelectColumn(sqlQueryGenerator);
        JSONObject formData = sqlQueryGenerator.getFormData();
        this.columns = formData.getJSONArray("columns");
        this.aggregateJson = formData.getJSONObject("functions").getJSONArray("aggregate");
        this.aggregatesList = new ArrayList<Aggregate>();
        prepareAggregates();
        this.query = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public SelectColumn(SqlQueryGenerator sqlQueryGenerator) {
        this.sqlQueryGenerator = sqlQueryGenerator;
    }
```

But IntelliJ Code Analysis says the following about recursive calls. Basically I didn't understand the meaning. Can anyone elaborate to help me understand?

**Problem synopsis**

> Constructor has usage(s) but they all belong to recursive calls chain that has no members reachable from entry points.

**Problem resolution**

1. Safe delete
2. Comment out
3. Add as Entry Point

Comment: It means you've created an unreachable chain of calls to a constructor in your code. Basically, you have code that does stuff, but no way to get there.

Comment: Difficult to tell without further information. Perhaps we need the exact method where this call is placed and the constructr content of `Aggregate`.

Comment: Okay. I will update the question

Comment: Can you add SelectColumn constructor too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a warning from the *Unused declaration* inspection. IntelliJ IDEA thinks the constructor is not reachable from any entry points. The constructor is not unused however, but the usages are themselves unreachable.

If this is not the case for your code, it may be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the constructor of AggregateFunctions in the code that you call you go back to the method selectColumns() in the other class. This way a recurrsion is never going to end.

My guess is that either here

```
 JSONObject formData = sqlQueryGenerator.getFormData();
```

Or somewhere in here:

```
 this.selectColumn = new SelectColumn(sqlQueryGenerator);
```

You go to the previous class and to the same method that creates a new aggreggate and a loop is happening.

You call the AggregateFunction with this - which is the same object. But then in the constructor you call methods of this. Check these methods and if any of them has another creation of AggregateFunction object - there is your problem.

Comment: AggregateFunctions is created only once

Comment: Yeah but this message means that there is a recurrsion. And looking in your code I believe it is the reason.
You have created it only once in the code that you have posted. But some of the code called in its constructor is probably creating another one. Can you post maybe the getFormData() method and the SelectColumn(sqlQueryGenerator) constructor?

Comment: formData is a member variable in SqlQueryGenerator. And the method getFormData is a getter only. The SelectColumns costructor already posted. And formData is a net.sf.JSONObject

Comment: Maybe it is in the prepareAggregates() method?

Comment: You can try debugging it step by step and see if it loops

Comment: It just uses the SqlQueryGenerator two methods. Nothing in those methods have loops or recursions. Simple string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was because the object was not used anywhere else